# Split array into multiple array by inner element

Tags: arrays, split

```
[19] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2015-03-02
            [supervisor] => 16
            [avg] => 1.50
        )
[20] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2015-03-03
        [supervisor] => 16
        [avg] => 1.50
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2015-03-04
        [supervisor] => 16
        [avg] => 1.50
    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2015-01-02
        [supervisor] => 26
        [avg] => 
    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2015-01-05
        [supervisor] => 26
        [avg] => 
    )
```

I have this array. I want to split this single array to 2 array by supervisor.
For example here only 2 different supervisor (16, 26). I want separate array for both.
like :
array 1:

```
[20] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2015-03-03
        [supervisor] => 16
        [avg] => 1.50
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2015-03-04
        [supervisor] => 16
        [avg] => 1.50
    )


Array 2: 
[22] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2015-01-02
        [supervisor] => 26
        [avg] => 
    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2015-01-05
        [supervisor] => 26
        [avg] => 
    )
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this in `PHP` ?

If so..

Create a new array for supervisors

```
$supervisors = array();
```

Firstly loop the current array

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value):
  $supervisor = $value['supervisor'];
  //Add more data to the array here
  $supervisors[$supervisor] = //Array of info you require
endforeach;
```

Comment: Perfect, if you could accept/vote up the answer that would be ace. :)

Comment: it does not allow me to vote because i need minimum 15 reputation. when i will have i will definitely vote you.

Comment: No worries enjoy :) programming is addictive!